# My ubuntu software centre catalog doesn't get updated

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, software-center

There are so many applications on [Ubuntu Apps website](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/) which when i try to open with Ubuntu software center, they are no where to be found!

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you select *Software Sources* from the edit menu and make sure that the (universe) and the (multiverse) options are checked?

Once it is done make sure to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Also in the software center technical items are usually hidden. You can display these hidden items by clicking the link in the lower left hand corner (after you have issued a search).

Comment: They are already checked!